# Which props are injected by `connect()` of `react-redux`?

Tags: redux, react-redux, documentation

It looks like the [official docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns) of `react-redux` does not provide full list of props are injected by `connect()`.

> The return of connect() is a wrapper function that takes your
>   component and returns a wrapper component with the additional props it
>   injects.

What is the additional props beside the props which are added by `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps`. For example, `dispatch` prop is injected in all component but it is not specified in the docs.

Is there any other prop being injected like `dispatch`? Will this behavior be stable in the future release?

If `dispatch` is injected. I also hope that `getState` is injected.

Comment: The behavior is declared in [the API docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object) already. If (and only if) `mapDispatchToProps` is not provided, `dispatch` will be injected to the wrapped component. Thank you acemarke in discord thread

Comment: Is there anyone show me how to close the question but keep it available for others to see it?

Comment: You can just answer your own question - add all the relevant links that helped you and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

`connect()` wrapper function without props inject just dispatch and don't listen to store.

```
export default connect()(YourComponent)
```

Do some research on code https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/tree/master/src/connect and you'll find your answer in two files/functions:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js

```
export function whenMapDispatchToPropsIsMissing(mapDispatchToProps) {
  return !mapDispatchToProps
    ? wrapMapToPropsConstant(dispatch => ({ dispatch })) // ***** inject dispatch
    : undefined
}
```

and

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapStateToProps.js

```
export function whenMapStateToPropsIsMissing(mapStateToProps) {
  return !mapStateToProps
    ? wrapMapToPropsConstant(() => ({})) // ***** empty object
    : undefined
}
```